# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.IMemoryCache'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, webapi

I have a `WEB API` using .NET 6. I used [MemoryCache](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/) to store data. But when I run the Api I get the following error:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.IMemoryCache'

**myContoroler:**

```
public class myContoroler : Controller
{
    private readonly MemoryCache _memoryCache = new MemoryCache(optionsAccessor: null);

    
   [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> myAPI(Model modelS)
    {
      var users = _memoryCache.Get("UserData")
      ...
    }

 }
```

Comment: Are you sure your Controller does not have a Constructor where you inject IMemoryCache?

Comment: @Ralf I wrote this api as a test to use cache memory. If it is ok, I will use it in the main project

Comment: You are aware that what you show means having a unique cache for every single request? Caching is normally for sharing data just creating a new cache for every call does not do that. The Cache is lost after every request. But the error you show has nothing to do with the code you show. You get that exception when you have unresolved instances when doing dependency injection and that happens typically in the constructor.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

in your `Startup.cs` file, you need to introduce `MemoryCache`:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

If there is no `Startup.cs` file, this should be done in `Program.cs` (in `.NET 6.0`, Startup.cs class is removed and Program.cs class is the place where register the dependencies of the application and the middleware.)

```
 builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();
```

It is also recommended to use dependency injection to use the `MemoryCache` in the controller:

```
public class myContoroler : Controller
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public myContoroler(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
         _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> myAPI(Model modelS)
    {
        var users = _memoryCache.Get("UserData")
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: The constructor body line will not compile. The `_memoryCache` field must be of type `IMemoryCache`.